# How to finish an activity from BaseAdapter in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Explanation:
            I know this is my repeated question.Understand the flow of my application.
I have multiple fragments in my navigationDrawer when i am in one of my fragment.This fragment call a BaseAdapter adapter and select the value from fragment.After selected an item from my fragment i goes to my mainActivity

Here is my Adapter code

```
package com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.adapter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.Handler.DatabaseHandler;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.MainActivity;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.R;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.model.State;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.model.Users;

import java.util.List;

public class StateSelectionAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private List<State> state_list;
    private int mselectedVariant;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private DatabaseHandler db;

    public StateSelectionAdapter(Context context,List<State> state_list,int mselectedVariant){
        this.context=context;
        this.state_list=state_list;
        this.mselectedVariant=mselectedVariant;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return state_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return state_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class Holder{
        TextView state_name;
        RadioButton radioButton;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder=new Holder();

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.radiolistviewrow,null);

            holder.state_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MainText);
            holder.radioButton=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_Choice);

            holder.state_name.setText(this.state_list.get(position).getState_name());
            if(holder.radioButton.isChecked()){

            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(position==mselectedVariant){
            holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            holder.radioButton.setChecked(false);
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mselectedVariant=position;
                db=new DatabaseHandler(context);

                Users user=new Users();
                user.setId("1");
                user.setSelectState(state_list.get(position).getId());
                int no=db.updateUser(user);
                if(no > 0){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Your state is:"+state_list.get(position).getState_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Your state"+state_list.get(position).getState_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                StateSelectionAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Intent i=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
                ((Activity)(context)).finish();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is an error which i got

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays, PID: 14827
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.app.MyApplication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
at com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.adapter.StateSelectionAdapter$1.onClick(StateSelectionAdapter.java:105)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my singleton class namely MyApplication.java

```
package com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.app;


import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.LoginActivity;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.helper.MyPreferenceManager;

public class MyApplication extends Application{
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private static MyApplication mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private MyPreferenceManager pref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
    public MyPreferenceManager getPrefManager() {
        if (pref == null) {
            pref = new MyPreferenceManager(this);
        }

        return pref;
    }
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this is because you are extending `Application` in myApplication.

Comment: it's really need to extend an Application in MyApplication class so what is the alternative option to overcome of this problem?

Comment: please paste manifest file

Comment: the context should be of activity not for complete app, one work around is, just pass two context to the adapter constructor, one context, of the activity and one that you are currently using, when you want to finish the activity then typecast the first context to activity and finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `Activity` reference as a `Context` in `BaseAdapter` class. 
That will work perfectly.

Here you are passing `Application` reference as `Context` so the `Application` is not casting to `Activity`.

Use the `Activity` reference where you are creating the instance of this adapter and if you are creating this `Adapter` in `Fragment` then use `getActivity()` method as context.

Comment: Like this `StateSelectionAdapter adapte = new StateSelectionAdapter(getActivity(),.......);`